# How to add extra(calculated) columns to a pandas pivot table

Tags: python, pandas

I am making a monthly student attendance report in my Django project using pandas pivot table.
Following is the code in my view :

```
*attend = StudentAttendance.objects.filter(ClassKey_id=2, Date__month=9).values('EnrollID_id','EnrollID__AcademicRollNo','EnrollID__AdminKey__SNameE', 'Date', 'Status' ).order_by('Date', 'id')*
 
*df = pd.DataFrame(attend)
table = df.pivot_table(index=['EnrollID__AcademicRollNo', 'EnrollID__AdminKey__SNameE'], columns=[pd.to_datetime(df.Date).dt.day], values=['Status'], aggfunc=','.join)*

*context={ 'table':table.to_html(table_id='dataframe') }
return render(request, 'student/attendance_report.html', context)*
```

In my template I have *{{table|safe}}*

With the data I have in my database I’m able to achieve the following table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MAbGm.png)

What I am looking for is to add three more columns to get Present, Absent and leave percentages calculated. And should look similar to this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UQ9R5.png)

Can anyone please suggest how I can go about this or any other best approach to handle this . Thank you.

Comment: what did you try? You should calculate values before sending to template

Comment: tried few things this is one of them but did not get the desired result
df.groupby('EnrollID_id')['Status'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts(normalize=True).groupby(level=0).head(1))

Comment: always put code, data and full error message as text (not screenshot, not link) in question (not in comment).  It will be more readable and more people will see it - so more people can help you.

Comment: it would be simpler if you would create `minimal working code` with example data in code - so we could simply copy and run it (to test ideas)

Comment: thank you for your suggestion